# manipulate data of ConnectableObserver

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I am using connectableObserver in my websocket and I need to manipulate the object to transform it to another object but I cant seem to do it with flatMap(). Here is the Code:

```
@Override
public ConnectableObservable<Object> getWebSocketObservable() {
    return getDataManager().getWebSocketObservable();
}
```

`getWebSocketObservable` returns a `ConnectableObservable<Pair<Boolean,String>>`. I wanted to manipulate it to become another object(or in this case just Object). And on a side note. In that snippet it doesn't accept the return value even though it only requires a generalized "Object". Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: `but I cant seem to do it with flatMap()` - what have you tried and what you got in output?

Comment: `In that snippet it doesn't accept the return value even though it only requires a generalized "Object"` - can you clarify what you mean by telling this?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty uncommon to return `ConnectableObservable` as a source because you'll lose this type immediately upon the first transformation. Let the client use `publish()` or `share()` on a regular `Observable` you return instead:

```
@Override
public Observable<Object> getWebSocketObservable() {
    return getDataManager().getWebSocketObservable()
        .cast(Object.class);
}

ConnectableObservable<Object> obs = getWebSocketObservable()
    .publish();

obs.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
obs.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);

obs.connect();
```

Note also that Java doesn't have the concept of explicit co- and contravariance in type signatures, unlike C#, thus you can't downcast an `Observable<T>` to an `Observable<Object>` even though `T extends Object`. In this case, you can either try to `cast()` or force cast via `(Observable)obs` and then `@SuppressWarnings` the unchecked and raw types warnings

Answer (score -1):

> The ConnectableObservable will initially emit nothing. When calling
>   connect, it will create a new subscription to its source observable
>   (the one we called publish on). It will begin receiving events and
>   pushing them to its subscribers. All of the subscribers will receive
>   the same events at the same time, as they are practically sharing the
>   same subscription: the one that connect created.

```
ConnectableObservable<Long> cold = Observable.interval(200, 
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).publish();
cold.connect();

cold.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("First: " + i));
cold.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
// Be notified on the main thread
cold.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
// Manipulation logic can replace this line
cold.map(longVar -> return Utils.manupulationOfConnectableObservable(input))
cold.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Second: " + i));
```

Implement Utils.manupulationOfConnectableObservable(input) as per requirements.

> A ConnectableObservable resembles an ordinary Observable,

except that it does not begin emitting items when it is subscribed to, but only when its connect() method is called. In this way you can wait for all intended Subscribers to Observable.subscribe() to the Observable before the Observable begins emitting items.

As it is mentioned in the [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/ConnectableObservable.html), that **A ConnectableObservable resembles an ordinary Observable**. So we can apply same RxJava operators which can be applied to Observable.

Comment: yes that much I know. my question is I wanted my subscriber to receive a manipulated data and I want to do it along the stream.

Comment: Your answer looks like an answer to following question: "What is `ConnectableObservable`?"

Comment: @azizbekian I have have modified my answer, please have a look.